# Best practice for the enumeration of n boolean variables in C++

Tags: c++, enumeration, brute-force

I want to enumerate all the possible values of 1<N<32 boolean variables.
My thought is that everything can be stored inside a 32-bit integer and
it suffices to let the compiler do the iteration job for me.

Hence I was thinking of doing something like:

```
for (int i=0;i<(1>>N);i++){
    std::bitset<32> T(i);
    ...
    some code using the bitset
    ...
}
```

However, I guess there is some time lost in the creation of a new
bitset each time, isn't it?

Is there a more orthodox practice to enumerate over a bitset/array of bool?

Thank you !

Comment: *"However, I guess there is some time lost in the creation of a new bitset each time, isn't it?"* You should only worry about that if your program does not meet performance requirements and after profiling it you find this exact loop to be the bottleneck. Compiler may be smart enough to put the bitset in a register, without creating any object.

Comment: `std::array<bool, SIZE>` and `std::next_permutation` sounds like a possible solution

Comment: Use an unsigned type for bit operations, not `int`, to avoid various problems with the sign bit or overflow. For the left operand of the shift, use a constant of the type you are using, such as `1u` for `unsigned int`. Use left shift (`<<`), not right shift (`>>`). Be sure that you are sticking to `N` < 32 for a 32-bit `unsigned int` (or `N` < 31 for `int`), or `1u<<N` (or `1<<N`) will be undefined.

Comment: `(1>>N)` does not seem very useful.

Comment: Your bits are already set, in your `i`. What can you do with the `bitset` that you can't do with that `int` value?